# Enabling/disabling bookmarks in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

My bookmark window looks like this:

[image]

Yesterday though suddenly and out of nowhere there were one check box at the left of each bookmark. Until then I didn't know (or didn't care) that you can enable and disable bookmarks in Visual Studio (2012).

Today the checkboxes are gone. :-( I can still enable and disable them via the menu option Edit -> Bookmarks -> Enable Bookmark. I could assign this function to a shortcut key combo, I guess.

But how can I get the check boxes back?

---

**Update:** The same applies to VS2013.

**Update:** ... and to VS2015.

**Update:** Also to VS2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view this is a VS-Bug.

My CheckBoxes are also "away" or better seems to be away. **When you click the position where the CheckBox actually is it still works.**

Means: When I click left to the bookmark "flag" (where check box normally is) the bookmarks still can be enable/disabled.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: Can you confirm my confirm the "CheckBox is invisible but still functional"-effect?

Comment: There might be a dependency to the graphics hardware and drivers, whether the bug appears or not. On my old PC with Intel integrated graphics the bug appeared. Now with nVidia hardware it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

BTW: This is the original thread in connect.microsoft:

[Bookmark Window: Checkbox for enabling/disabling bookmarks is invisible](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/799739)

Comment: Currently I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. And no bookmark checkboxes.